# Understanding Physics Materials

Tags: unity, physics

I have been reading the documentation about Physics materials, and it really seems very incomplete to me. When I try to work with it, I get so many questions... Maybe can someone help me wrap my head around how it works?

- Why is there a `physics material` field for the `Rigidbody2D`, but also another in the `BoxCollider2D`?
- Do they work differently, depending on which you put it?
- What happens if you put different materials, one on the RB and one in the collider with different settings?
- If a player is standing in a platform, and you want it to *bounce*, or *slide*... do you set that on the player? Or in the platform?

**Update**

As suggested in the comments, I did some experimenting and this is what I saw:

- When I put contradicting materials in the `RigidBody2D` and the `Collider2D`, the one in the collider seems to take precedence. Not sure what is the purpose of the one in the Rigidbody.
- If both are the same, well, they just behave like one of them alone. The value isn't added

Comment: Your middle two bullet points look like they can be answered by experiment. Make three identical bouncing ball setups. Then assign a zero-bounce material to the collider on one, the rigidbody on the other, and both on the third. Test and compare the differences. Repeat for various other permutations, then update the question with your findings.

Comment: Added my findings

Comment: If you put a material on your rigidbody, does it apply to all colliders under that body that don't specify their own material?

Comment: I did not try to use it in a GO with multiple colliders. So I did what you said, and the way it looks, the PhysicsMaterial in the Rigidbody applies to every collider on the GO, but this behaviour can be overriden by every individual collider. Is that it? Is that the meaning behind it all?

Comment: Based on your experiments, it sounds like setting the material on the rigidbody is a way to provide a blanket default for any colliders that don't specify their own material. Moreover, it looks like this is a question you've been able to answer through your own experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

After following @DMGregory 's suggestions  in the comments I have reached the following conclusions.

If you set a physics material to a Rigidbody2D, that material will apply. But if you also set another Physics Material to a collider in the same GameObject, this will override the Material in the Rigidbody2D.

Apparently this is meaningless when you only have 1 object with one collider, but if you were to have an GameObject with multiple colliders, and you wanted the GO to react differently, depending on which Collider2D it lands, you can apply a Physics Material to each collider, to achieve more complex behaviours.

**Summary**

Use the "Physics Material" slot in the collider only to override the one in the Rigidbody2D. If you only have one collider, it is pretty meaningless and you can ignore it.